# VMware view for Remote Non Admin Users

Tags: vmware-view

Has anyone came up with a way that I can connect to a view enviroment and not have to copy files or install software yet? I have heard of virtualizing the client. I would like to see it work similar to connecting to a view enviroment using a Linux machine. Where the desktop is launched through the browser.

Comment: Is this question about the "VMware View" product (http://www.vmware.com/products/view/)? Or is it about "viewing VMware"?

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you, we'll need some details about your environment.  Are you running ESX/ESXi or Virtual Center / vSphere? (or VMWare Server or VMWare Workstation?)

We're running Virtual Center 2 with ESX 3.5 hosts, so I'll give you those instructions (which will work against either the Virtual Center server or a standalone ESX host):

Add the restricted user as a Virtual Machine Operator:

- Open the Virtual Infrastructure Client
- selecting the Virtual Machine you wish to grant access, and going to the Permissions tab.
- Right click inside the window and choose Add..
- From here you can add a user on the local host (or from an AD or LDAP if you've integrated).
- Choose Virtual Machine User as the role

Instructions for opening the guest as the restricted user:

- Browse to the server's address, where you should be presented with a login page (there will probably be an ssl cert prompt first)
- Select a guest VM and open the console.
- There is a prompt to run an ActiveX control in order to be able to see the desktop.
- I haven't tried from a Linux desktop, so I can't tell you how that works.